# SailsJS: beforeUpdate (Lifecycle callback), access current values

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

It's clear how to access the new values, the first argument contains them

`beforeUpdate: function (values, cb) {....}`

But how can I access the current values, that are to be replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order do access current values you will have to make the call and get the current record.

```
models/user.js
beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {
    User.findOne(this.update.arguments[0].id || this.update.arguments[0]).exec(err, function(originalUser){/*...*/})
}
```

Also check out  https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1004#issuecomment-102432862 , where this issue is being discussed. Should provide insight into getting the ID and a current solution.

The solution above was updated to reflect the comments.

Comment: The problem is, that if I try to update using a URL, `values` does not contain the `id` attribute because it was not a part of the update, for example running this URL: `http://localhost:1337/user/update/555f6015f7b73f2b085396dc?pname=abcd`, id will not exist in `values`

Comment: Awesome, so as suggested in the github issue discussion you linked, the `id` can be retrieved using `this.update.arguments[0]`.
Thanks!

Comment: correct. Note that if you do an update that passes the id directly into the model via an object ```(ex Model.update({id:X})``` then it will break because that would be ```this.update.arguments[0].id```. Easily planned for. You could simply do ```var id = this.update.arguments[0].id || this.update.arguments[0]```

Comment: Has anyone had problems with this.update.arguments suddenly starting to return null? Could be a breaking change in one of the packages...

Comment: @Leo thanks for tracking this down https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1004#issuecomment-112604499

Comment: `this.update.arguments` is not defined in sails 0.12.11, so it does not work. It might have something to do with the async module.