# Pass criteria to validation and lifecycle callbacks in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js, waterline

#### Update

This, as pointed by [@Alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202697) in the comments section, is similar to another question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403501/sailsjs-beforeupdate-lifecycle-callback-access-current-values#answer-30403858) on S.O. The answer points to a [well known issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1004) (or feature?) within the waterline core.

I will let the question open though, because both this question and the pointed question from above are different but rely on the same underlying functionality to work.

Will come with the complete solution once this will be available in waterline.

---

#### OP

Is there a way to pass criteria in validation and beforeUpdate callbacks?

The use case scenario for this is that I want to grab the primaryKey value from the criteria and query the database based on this value.

Concrete example: I have 2 tables, authors and articles (with one author having many articles). Now, I want the title property for each author's article to be unique.

So:

```
var author = {
        name: "Sam Johnson",
        id: 123
    },
    articles = [{
        id: 1,
        title: "title1",
        owner: 123
    }, {
        id: 2,
        title: "title2",
        owner: 123
    }];
```

Now, when updating first article's title, to check if it's not already existent;

```
Article.update(1, {title: "title2"});
```

Now, I have provided a custom validator for the title property within the article model, like this:

```
... // irrelevant
attributes: {
    ... // irrelevant
    title: {
        type: "string",
        required: true,
        uniqueTitle: function(cb) {
            console.log(this) // {title: "newTitleValue"}
            // so this is quite usless :(
            cb();
        }
    }
},
beforeUpdate: [
    function _checkTitle(values, cb) {
        console.log(values) // same as above {title: "newTitleValue"}
        console.log(this) // the model, with no criteria or primaryKey property set, which becomes useless :(
        cb();
    }
]
...
```

Any thoughts on how to access the update criteria within those hooks? :(

Comment: I guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403501/sailsjs-beforeupdate-lifecycle-callback-access-current-values#answer-30403858) can help you

Comment: @AlexisN-o Yeah, that's basically how they solved the problem. But the issue from waterline, i.e. [#1004](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1004), is basically this question.